Compiling Python (3.13) with custom ncurses library path
I would like to compile Python 3.13 (on CentOS 7.9), and my 'ncurses' compiled libraries are in a non-standard location (~/custom/gcc-14.2/lib/).
Following the configuration documentation, I define CURSES_LIBS
# I use a custom compiler:
export CC=gcc-14.2 CXX=g++-14.2

# PWD is Python3.13.0
# I compile in a subfolder:
mkdir build && cd build

CURSES_LIBS="-L$HOME/custom/gcc-14.2" ../configure \
    --prefix=$HOME/custom/gcc-14.2 \
    --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions \
    --enable-optimizations --with-lto \
    --with-platlibdir=lib64 \
    --with-ensurepip=install \
    --enable-shared 

but the standard output contains these lines:
checking for ncursesw... no                                                                                                                                                                   
checking for ncurses... no                                                                                                                                                                    
checking for ncursesw/curses.h... no                                                                                                                                                          
checking for ncursesw/ncurses.h... no                                                                                                                                                         
checking for ncursesw/panel.h... no                                                                                                                                                           
checking for ncurses/curses.h... no                                                                                                                                                           
checking for ncurses/ncurses.h... no                                                                                                                                                          
checking for ncurses/panel.h... no                                                                                                                                                            
checking for curses.h... no                                                                                                                                                                   
checking for ncurses.h... no

and then when running make I get these errors (abbreviated):
[...]

gcc-14.2 -pthread  -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall    -fno-semantic-interposition -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c11 -Wext
ra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fvisibility=hidden -fprofile-generate -I../Include/internal -I../Include/i
nternal/mimalloc -IObjects -IInclude -IPython -I. -I../Include   -fPIC -fPIC -c ../Modules/_cursesmodule.c -o Modules/_cursesmodule.o                                                         
In file included from ../Modules/_cursesmodule.c:116:                                                                                                                                         
../Include/py_curses.h:80:5: error: unknown type name ‘WINDOW’                                                                                                                                
   80 |     WINDOW *win;                                                                                                                                                                      
      |     ^~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                            
../Modules/_cursesmodule.c:173:36: error: ‘FALSE’ undeclared here (not in a function)                                                                                                         
  173 | static int initialised_setupterm = FALSE;                                                                                                                                             
      |                                    ^~~~~                                                                                                                                              
../Modules/_cursesmodule.c: In function ‘PyCursesCheckERR’:                                                                                                                                   
../Modules/_cursesmodule.c:213:17: error: ‘ERR’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘ERA’?                                                                                  
  213 |     if (code != ERR) {                                                                                                                                                                
      |                 ^~~                                                                                                                                                                   
      |                 ERA                                     

[...]

../Modules/_cursesmodule.c: In function ‘_curses_start_color_impl’:
../Modules/_cursesmodule.c:4228:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 4228 | }
      | ^
../Modules/_cursesmodule.c: In function ‘_curses_meta_impl’:
../Modules/_cursesmodule.c:3624:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 3624 | }
      | ^
make[2]: *** [Modules/_cursesmodule.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [profile-gen-stamp] Erreur 2
make: *** [profile-run-stamp] Erreur 2

Also the executable installed with make install cannot run:
$ ~/custom/gcc-14.2/bin/python3.13 -c 'print("Hello")'

Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Fatal Python error: Failed to import encodings module
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fd963713780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>

Any idea on the proper way to define CURSES_LIBS? Or is there anything else to set up?

You're setting -L flag, but not -I flag - that could explain missing headers.

Thanks for the suggestion (I am not familiar with these linking options). I tried but it still does not work...
